# Perron's Formula with $\rm{si}$-Remainder

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series, mellin-transform

I'm studying the book `Multiplicative Number Theory I. Classical Theory' by Hugh L. Montgomery and Robert C. Vaughan, and I don't understant a step of the proof for Perron's Formula(in Section 5.1) with $\rm{si}$-remainder, which states that $$\sum_{n\le x}'a(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}\alpha(s)\cdot\frac{x^s}{s}ds+R$$ where $\alpha(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)n^{-s}$ has abscissa of absolute convergence $\sigma_a$, $\sigma>\max\{0, \sigma_a\}$, and $$R = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{x/2<n<x}a_n{\rm si}\left(T\log\frac{x}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{x<n<2x}a_n{\rm si}\left(T\log\frac{n}{x}\right) + O\left(\frac{4^\sigma+x^\sigma}{T}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{n^\sigma}\right).$$ In the proof, the authors first change sum and integral so that $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}\alpha(s)\cdot\frac{x^s}{s}ds = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^s\frac{ds}{s}.$$ Then the authors says that it suffices to show $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\sigma-iT}^{\sigma+iT}y^s\frac{ds}{s} = \begin{cases}1+O(y^\sigma/T) &\text{if }y\ge2\\ 1+ \frac{1}{\pi}{\rm si}(T\log y)+O(2^\sigma/T) &\text{if }1\le y\le 2\\ -\frac{1}{\pi}{\rm si}(T\log y)+O(2^\sigma/T) &\text{if }1/2\le y\le 1\\ O(y^\sigma/T) &\text{if }y\le 1/2\end{cases}$$ for $\sigma>0$.

What I don't understand is how this suffices for the case $\frac{1}{2}\le y\le 2$. The error term $2^\sigma$ cannot be bounded by $(4^\sigma+x^\sigma)/n^\sigma$ as long as my calculation is correct. We have the condition $x/2\le n\le 2x$, but this did not help. The only thing worked is to change the last error to $O((4x)^\sigma/T\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|/n^\sigma)$. Is this a typo? Or there is a way to justify this error bound?

Comment: The treatments of Montgomery & Vaughan are overcomplicating the derivation of Perron's formula. For this topic, I would recommend reading chapter 3 of Titchmarsh's _Theory of the Riemann zeta-function_.

Comment: Actually, I've read Tom Apostol's derivation of Perron's formula. Also I am aware that the error bound is quite stronger than we want to use in practice, as the authors wrote. But I just want to understand this Theorem.

Comment: Apostol's formula is expressed in terms of infinite integrals, but you need the truncated version to derive big O error terms for the prime number theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, you can always assume $x\ge4$ and $\sigma$ is fixed, so the last term eventually becomes

$$
\ll{x^\sigma\over T}\sum_{n\ge1}{|a_n|\over n^\sigma},
$$

which is sufficient for applications.

Comment: But I am not even sure the above bound holds, and I think also this version may not be justified using argument of Montgomery and Vaughan, since $2^\sigma\le (x/n)^\sigma$ only for $x\ge 2n$.

Comment: My point is that $(4x)^\sigma\ll x^\sigma$ when $\sigma$ is bounded (which is always the case in applications).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for explanation.